# javascript string remove white spaces and hyphens

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to remove white spaces and hyphens from a given string.

```
 var string = "john-doe alejnadro";
 var new_string = string.replace(/-\s/g,"")
```

Doesn't work, but this next line works for me:

```
var new_string = string.replace(/-/g,"").replace(/ /g, "")
```

How do I do it in one go ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use [alternation](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/articles/javascript-regular-expressions):

```
var new_string = string.replace(/-|\s/g,"");
```

`a|b` will match *either* `a` or `b`, so this matches both hyphens and whitespace.

**Example:**

```
> "hyphen-containing string".replace(/-|\s/g,"")
'hyphencontainingstring'
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to use:

```
 var new_string = string.replace(/[-\s]/g,"")
```

`/-\s/` means hyphen followed by white space.

Answer (score 4):

Use This for Hyphens

```
var str="185-51-671";
var newStr = str.replace(/-/g, "");
```

White Space

```
var Actuly = newStr.trim();
```

Comment: .trim() will only remove whitespace at the beginning or end of a string